# Error: No CUDA support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in throw_no_cuda

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cuda, nvidia

Возникла проблема с использованием в cuda в OpenCV.

Скриншот с проблемами. Библиотека собрана со всеми нужными флагами, но почему пишет, что без CUDA разобраться не могу. Скриншоты с CMake и IDE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Cuda SDK установлен? Сmake же прямо жалуется на его отсутствие.

Comment: @VTT, здравствуйте, а я и не знал что это нужно. Спасибо, что указали на проблему.